# Derivative of inverse function at a point.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f\left(x\right)=x^{13}+3x^{9}+2x^{5}+x^{2}+x+2$ find $\left(f^{-1}\right)'\left(1\right)$. Can somebody show me the method? I am a little confused.

Answer (score 2):

The function value of $f$ evaluated at point $P$ where $x = 1$ equals $f(1) = 10.$ The first derivative $f'$ evaluated at $P$ is given by $f'(1) = 13 + 27 + 10 + + 2 + 1 = 53$.

We can now write an expression for the tangent through $P$:

$y = 10 + 53 (x-1)$

In the inverse function the roles of $x$ and $y$ are reversed. The (new) tangent is therefore given by:

$x = 10 + 53 (y-1)$  which can be rewritten as

$y = 1 + \frac 1 {53} (x - 10)$

It follows that the derivative of the inverse function in point $P$ equals $\frac 1 {53}$.

Comment: How did you get 9 in your first equation... Isn't value of function 10 at that point

Comment: Yes, it looks like I made a simple mistake. Thank you for pointing this out !

Comment: I have corrected my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In general, assuming everything exists and is well behaved,

$$(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$

Can you do it now?

Comment: I should have clarified I have the formula mentioned, but my question is how to find $f^{-1}\left(x\right)$ for a function like this? Am I missing something simple?

Comment: No, I just checked the calculation and it looks quite inelegant. Are you sure all the coefficients in your polynomial are correct? Of course it could just be that the exercise is meant to be 'real world' in its lack of a nice, closed form answer.

Comment: I looked again, and that is what the problem says.

Comment: Looks like you just have to slug it out carrying decimals in the calculations. (BTW, Krampus, great name. A Krampus set this problem I think. ;-) )